# Не работает код. invalid syntax в месте print(price manes "")

Tags: python, if, syntax

В магазине продают несколько видов шаров: красные, желтые и зеленые, белые, синие. В пачке несколько штук. Красные стоят 50р, желтый 80р, зеленые по 47р, белые 40р, синие 80р.
Необходимо написать программу на Python, считающую общую сумму купленных пачек шариков.

Ввод
красные
зеленые
желтые
Вывод
177

```
x = input()
y = input()
z = input()
names = ["Красные"],["Желтые"], ["Зеленые"], ["Белые"], ["Синие"]
price = [50], [80], [47], [40], [80],
print(price manes "")

SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

Код не работает( Может проделать это с if?

---

мне нужно вводить не число, а текст (красные, зеленые, синие) и чтобы выводом было число (стоимость определенных шариков). Стоимость на каждый цвет уже задана. if - чтобы выстроить цепочку отношений между стоимостью отдельного и его цветом.

Comment: а что у вас означает эта строка print(price manes "") ?

Comment: "Perhaps you forgot a comma?" -> "Возможно, вы забыли запятую?"

Comment: Чтобы в выводе появилось число 177, в коде хотя бы 1 раз должен появиться знак ``+``. Программы делают то, что вы пишите в коде, а не то, что вы придумали у себя в голове.

Comment: Во-первых не `manes`, а `names`, а во-вторых в ошибке всё написано, хотя всё-равно вы печатаете что-то странное.

Answer (score 0):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##VY9NCsIwEIX3PcWQVQIigopScOnKI4gLkagFTUOM2CKCVnDjGbxDVaqi1DNMTlRT/9DFg@Hjzcx7MtRDX5SzTKvQdQAkNGBO8GqWGJsVpmaLCXGhWioAwRMmeDPRm9Wf7Jwzq4@zUsvp/ul8k9zXwwumVq/FRf5JeULTyXRMZdsTcqopK478GVeUdaDvKwjAE6C6YsBpmTHm8KDHpYYWD5tK@cr93iC4M2sbLsU7HvEOZoMHTEyEMVhmB8Ky7L@S85/b@a32AA)

```
try:
  p = {"красные": 50, "желтые": 80, "зеленые": 47, "белые": 40, "cиние": 80}
  print(sum(p[input().lower()] for x in range(3)))
except KeyError:
  print("Нужного цвета нет")
```

```
красные
зеленые
желтые
```

```
177
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @11010000100110, прими ответ галочкой слева.